# How to remove all empty array childrens [] from a nested JSON recursively

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, lodash

I've a JSON response as below.I'm using nested JSON data from my GeoRegionCountries APIController & custom class TreeView is used to format the data as per the required nested structure of plugin I'm using. I am using a combo multi select Treeview using this jquery plugin Multi-Select Drop Down Tree Plugin you can see it by this link [jquery plugin Multi-Select Drop Down Tree Plugin](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Drop-Down-Combo-Tree.html)

```
[
          {
            "Id": 1,
            "Title": "United States",
            "ParentId": null,
            "Subs": [
              {
                "Id": 7,
                "Title": "Northwest",
                "ParentId": 1,
                "Subs": []
              },
              {
                "Id": 8,
                "Title": "Northeast",
                "ParentId": 1,
                "Subs": []
              },
              {
                "Id": 9,
                "Title": "Central",
                "ParentId": 1,
                "Subs": []
              },
              {
                "Id": 10,
                "Title": "Southwest",
                "ParentId": 1,
                "Subs": []
              },
              {
                "Id": 18,
                "Title": "Southeast",
                "ParentId": 1,
                "Subs": []
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Id": 2,
            "Title": "Canada",
            "ParentId": null,
            "Subs": []
          },
          {
            "Id": 3,
            "Title": "France",
            "ParentId": null,
            "Subs": []
          },
          {
            "Id": 4,
            "Title": "Germany",
            "ParentId": null,
            "Subs": []
          },
          {
            "Id": 5,
            "Title": "Australia",
            "ParentId": null,
            "Subs": []
          },
          {
            "Id": 6,
            "Title": "United Kingdom",
            "ParentId": null,
            "Subs": []
          }
        ]
```

I want to remove all "Subs" with empty array.

```
         [
          {
            "Id": 1,
            "Title": "United States",
            "ParentId": null,
            "Subs": [
              {
                "Id": 7,
                "Title": "Northwest",
                "ParentId": 1
              },
              {
                "Id": 8,
                "Title": "Northeast",
                "ParentId": 1
              },
              {
                "Id": 9,
                "Title": "Central",
                "ParentId": 1
              },
              {
                "Id": 10,
                "Title": "Southwest",
                "ParentId": 1
              },
              {
                "Id": 18,
                "Title": "Southeast",
                "ParentId": 1
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Id": 2,
            "Title": "Canada",
            "ParentId": null
          },
          {
            "Id": 3,
            "Title": "France",
            "ParentId": null
          },
          {
            "Id": 4,
            "Title": "Germany",
            "ParentId": null
          },
          {
            "Id": 5,
            "Title": "Australia",
            "ParentId": null
          },
          {
            "Id": 6,
            "Title": "United Kingdom",
            "ParentId": null
          }
        ]
```

What is the best way to deep clean this? I tried different solutions in Stackopverflow but all i got is Object object in place of empty Subs - which i don't want.

```
      [
          {
            "Id": 1,
            "Title": "United States",
            "ParentId": null,
            "Subs": [
              {
                "Id": 7,
                "Title": "Northwest",
                "ParentId": 1,
                Object object
              },
              {
                "Id": 8,
                "Title": "Northeast",
                "ParentId": 1,
                Object object
              },
              {
                "Id": 9,
                "Title": "Central",
                "ParentId": 1,
                Object object
              },
              {
                "Id": 10,
                "Title": "Southwest",
                "ParentId": 1,
                Object object
              },
              {
                "Id": 18,
                "Title": "Southeast",
                "ParentId": 1,
                Object object
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Id": 2,
            "Title": "Canada",
            "ParentId": null,
            Object object
          },
          {
            "Id": 3,
            "Title": "France",
            "ParentId": null,
            Object object
          },
          {
            "Id": 4,
            "Title": "Germany",
            "ParentId": null,
            Object object
          },
          {
            "Id": 5,
            "Title": "Australia",
            "ParentId": null,
            Object object
          },
          {
            "Id": 6,
            "Title": "United Kingdom",
            "ParentId": null,
            Object object
          }
        ]
```

which is not i want

Comment: share what you have tried, and what's going wrong in that.

Comment: HI! Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: One hint would be to use `delete` operator . https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Comment: I did answer your question, next time take the advice up

Answer (score 3):

You can use `_.transform()` to recursively check for a specific key (`Subs`), and remove it if it's value is empty:

```js
const { transform, isObject, isEmpty } = _;

const removeEmpty = (obj, key) =>
  transform(obj, (r, v, k) => {
    if(k === key && isEmpty(v)) return;
    r[k] = isObject(v) ? removeEmpty(v, key) : v;
  });

const tree = [{"Id":1,"Title":"United States","ParentId":null,"Subs":[{"Id":7,"Title":"Northwest","ParentId":1,"Subs":[]},{"Id":8,"Title":"Northeast","ParentId":1,"Subs":[]},{"Id":9,"Title":"Central","ParentId":1,"Subs":[]},{"Id":10,"Title":"Southwest","ParentId":1,"Subs":[]},{"Id":18,"Title":"Southeast","ParentId":1,"Subs":[]}]},{"Id":2,"Title":"Canada","ParentId":null,"Subs":[]},{"Id":3,"Title":"France","ParentId":null,"Subs":[]},{"Id":4,"Title":"Germany","ParentId":null,"Subs":[]},{"Id":5,"Title":"Australia","ParentId":null,"Subs":[]},{"Id":6,"Title":"United Kingdom","ParentId":null,"Subs":[]}]

const result = removeEmpty(tree, 'Subs');

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer would be this:

```js
let array =  [
  {
   'Id': 1,
   'Title': 'United States',
   'ParentId': null,
   'Subs': [
    {
     'Id': 7,
     'Title': 'Northwest',
     'ParentId': 1,
     'Subs': []
    },
    {
     'Id': 8,
     'Title': 'Northeast',
     'ParentId': 1,
     'Subs': []
    },
    {
     'Id': 9,
     'Title': 'Central',
     'ParentId': 1,
     'Subs': []
    },
    {
     'Id': 10,
     'Title': 'Southwest',
     'ParentId': 1,
     'Subs': []
    },
    {
     'Id': 18,
     'Title': 'Southeast',
     'ParentId': 1,
     'Subs': []
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   'Id': 2,
   'Title': 'Canada',
   'ParentId': null,
   'Subs': []
  },
  {
   'Id': 3,
   'Title': 'France',
   'ParentId': null,
   'Subs': []
  },
  {
   'Id': 4,
   'Title': 'Germany',
   'ParentId': null,
   'Subs': []
  },
  {
   'Id': 5,
   'Title': 'Australia',
   'ParentId': null,
   'Subs': []
  },
  {
   'Id': 6,
   'Title': 'United Kingdom',
   'ParentId': null,
   'Subs': []
  }
 ]
let newArray = array.map(item=> {
 if (item.Subs.length===0){
  delete item.Subs
  return item
 }
 item.Subs = item.Subs.map(item=>{
  if (item.Subs.length===0){
   delete item.Subs
   return item
  }
 })
 return item
}
)
console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = [
          {
            "Id": 1,
            "Title": "United States",
            "ParentId": null,
            "Subs": [
              {
                "Id": 7,
                "Title": "Northwest",
                "ParentId": 1,
                "Subs": []
              },
              {
                "Id": 8,
                "Title": "Northeast",
                "ParentId": 1,
                "Subs": []
              },
              {
                "Id": 9,
                "Title": "Central",
                "ParentId": 1,
                "Subs": []
              },
              {
                "Id": 10,
                "Title": "Southwest",
                "ParentId": 1,
                "Subs": []
              },
              {
                "Id": 18,
                "Title": "Southeast",
                "ParentId": 1,
                "Subs": []
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Id": 2,
            "Title": "Canada",
            "ParentId": null,
            "Subs": []
          },
          {
            "Id": 3,
            "Title": "France",
            "ParentId": null,
            "Subs": []
          },
          {
            "Id": 4,
            "Title": "Germany",
            "ParentId": null,
            "Subs": []
          },
          {
            "Id": 5,
            "Title": "Australia",
            "ParentId": null,
            "Subs": []
          },
          {
            "Id": 6,
            "Title": "United Kingdom",
            "ParentId": null,
            "Subs": []
          }
        ];

data = data.map(row=>{
  if (!row.Subs.length) {
     let {Subs,...r} = row;
     return r;
  } return row
})

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

write two functions and pass the function that iterates through your array to a map function on data as shown below

```js
function formatData(val) {
  if (val.Subs.length > 0) val.Subs.map(a => a.Subs.length > 0 ? formatData(a.Subs) : deleteSubs(a));
  else deleteSubs(val);
  return val;
}

function deleteSubs(val) {
  delete val.Subs;
}

var data = [{
    "Id": 1,
    "Title": "United States",
    "ParentId": null,
    "Subs": [{
        "Id": 7,
        "Title": "Northwest",
        "ParentId": 1,
        "Subs": []
      },
      {
        "Id": 8,
        "Title": "Northeast",
        "ParentId": 1,
        "Subs": []
      },
      {
        "Id": 9,
        "Title": "Central",
        "ParentId": 1,
        "Subs": []
      },
      {
        "Id": 10,
        "Title": "Southwest",
        "ParentId": 1,
        "Subs": []
      },
      {
        "Id": 18,
        "Title": "Southeast",
        "ParentId": 1,
        "Subs": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "Title": "Canada",
    "ParentId": null,
    "Subs": []
  },
  {
    "Id": 3,
    "Title": "France",
    "ParentId": null,
    "Subs": []
  },
  {
    "Id": 4,
    "Title": "Germany",
    "ParentId": null,
    "Subs": []
  },
  {
    "Id": 5,
    "Title": "Australia",
    "ParentId": null,
    "Subs": []
  },
  {
    "Id": 6,
    "Title": "United Kingdom",
    "ParentId": null,
    "Subs": []
  }
]
console.log(data.map(formatData))
```